# How to remove json key value pair from json object array using java

Tags: java, json

I want to remove "status": "new" from JSON that I have stored in jsonObject using

```
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(responseStr);
        jsonObject =  (JSONObject) obj;
```

JSON structure --

```
{"actionName": "test"
"Data": [{

    "isActive": true,
    "Id": "1358",
    "status": "new"
}],
```

}

new JSON should look like this -

```
{"actionName": "test"
"Data": [{

    "isActive": true,
    "Id": "1358"
    
}],
```

}

I have tried jsonObj.remove("status") , but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over `Data` property which is a `JSON Array` and remove for every item `status` key.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class JsonSimpleApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject root = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(jsonFile));
        JSONArray dataArray = (JSONArray) root.get("Data");
        dataArray.forEach(item -> {
            JSONObject object = (JSONObject) item;
            object.remove("status");
        });

        System.out.println(root);
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{"Data":[{"Id":"1358","isActive":true}],"actionName":"test"}
```

Comment: it is working! thanks! One follow up question what if we have to remove more than one key value pair ? l

Comment: @user1992728, `JSONObject` is just a `Map` object with extra methods. You can remove as many keys as you want. In `forEach` method you can remove all keys specified in an `array` for example. Iterate over this array and remove every key from `JSONObject`.

Answer (score 1):

```
jsonObj.getJSONArray("Data").get(0).remove("status);
```

**#Updated Code-breakdown:**

```
JSONObject obj= (JSONObject) jsonObj.getJSONArray("Data").get(0);
   obj.remove("status");

   JSONArray newArr=new JSONArray();
   newArr.put(obj);
   jsonObj.put("Data", newArr);
```

It should do your work, haven't tested though.
First, your `Data` is JSONArray, retrieving that by `jsonObj.getJSONArray("Data")`, then access the array with `get(0)`[assuming, your array will contain only one entry like your example] and finally, removing that key by `remove` method.

Comment: hi thank you for the prompt reply, but i am getting the method getJSONArray(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject error.

Comment: what library are you using? org.json or Jackson?

Comment: org.json.simple.JSONObject

Comment: The method getJSONArray(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject--still facing same issue

Comment: I was using lib from this, please have a look here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20190722